# Best Way to Save or Store Cart Items by each user? (Best Practice or Way) [MERNG STACK]

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, apollo, apollo-client, shopping-cart

I'm trying to make an ecommerce for my personal project and I'm trying to use everything I've learned to do so. I currently have this code that allows you to store **`cartItems`** in a local Storage, but I believe it's incorrect what I did because in this scenario, for example, **`user 1`** added his items to the cart or products to the cart, and then **`user 2`** can access or have the same cart when I login with them. **Which is the best practice or choice for the user to save **`cartItems`**? Or, rather, what should I do?**

> Currently the technology I use the
> **M(ongoDB)E(xpress)R(eact)N(odejs)G(raphql)** and **Apollo** for my state management.

## Code

---

### CartContext:

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../auth";

export const CartContext = createContext();

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const cartFromLocalStorage =
    (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))) ||
    [];

  const [cartItems, setCartItem] = useState(cartFromLocalStorage);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      if (user) { // This just shows if the user is loggedIn
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      }
    }
  }, [cartItems]);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={[cartItems, setCartItem]}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This is my **`CartContext`**, where I can see what the user has added to their cart and call it whenever I want because it's a context that doesn't require to pass props to a component.

### Shop:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS_QUERY } from "../util/graphql/Queries";

import { Grid, Transition } from "semantic-ui-react";
import ProductCard from "../components/products/ProductCard";
import { CartContext } from "../context/cart/CartContext";

function Shop() {
  const { loading, data: Products } = useQuery(FETCH_PRODUCTS_QUERY);

  const { getProducts: products } = { ...Products };

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useContext(CartContext);

  const addToCart = (product) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id == product.id ? { ...exist, quantity: exist.quantity + 1 } : x
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  const ProductList = products?.map((product) => (
    <Grid.Column key={product.id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <ProductCard
        product={product}
        addToCart={(product) => addToCart(product)}
      />
    </Grid.Column>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <Grid columns={3}>
        <Grid.Row className="page-title">
          <h1>Recent Products</h1>
        </Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Row>
          {loading ? (
            <h1>Loading products..</h1>
          ) : (
            <Transition.Group>{ProductList}</Transition.Group>
          )}
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default Shop;
```

This is my Shop or where the Product is located as shown I passed the `addToCart function` to the `ProductCard` Component.

### ProductCard:

```
 import { Image, Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
    import Link from "next/link";
    import Rating from "../reviews/Rating";
    
    function ProductCard({ product, addToCart }) {
      const {
        id,
        name,
        featureImage,
        productCurrentPrice,
        productPreviousPrice,
        rating,
        numReviews,
      } = product;
    
      return (
        <>
          <Card>
            <Image
              src={featureImage}
              width={200}
              height={200}
              alt="Product Image"
              className="product-image"
            />
            <Card.Content>
              <Card.Header>
                <Link href={`/products/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Meta>
                <span className="date">
                  ₱{productCurrentPrice.toLocaleString()}
                </span>
                <span className="date">
                  <strike>₱{productPreviousPrice.toLocaleString()}</strike>
                </span>
                &nbsp;
                <span className="header">{percentOff} % OFF</span>
              </Card.Meta>
            </Card.Content>
            <Card.Content extra>
              <div className="ui two buttons">
                <button
                  className="ui basic green button"
                  onClick={() => addToCart(product)}
                >
                  Add To Cart
                </button>
              </div>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default ProductCard;
```

This is my ProductCard Component which when addToCart it will go to the localStorage just like this:

[image]

As shown above, the image the `cart key` is where all the products I added is inputted there. even when I logout the `cartItem` is still shown there, which it should not.

If you need anymore clarification or explanation, I can provide it, if code I will also provide I will be transparent as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each user has their own unique cart available, you can **save the cart info the along with the userId/username of the current *user*** as identifier. So when a user logs in you can just **fetch the their cart using that identifier of the user**

usually for storing such sensitive data it is better to save them directly in your DB rather than the local storage.

You can create an async Api call such that whenever you add items to cart, your corresponding data in table is also updated. Example a "Cart" table containing the current cart details of all users

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, so basically I have to create another table in the db and call it cart then filter out the data which contains thats current user identifier or in its case I could use the `userId`, you see after I add to cart I already have made the checkout process in which case that after I place the order the `cart` should be **going back to 0 or empty since I placed an order**,  so Im going to delete that data from the cart table after I placed that user?

Comment: you can clear the cart details when you have response from the checkout. Like if the checkout is successful and payment is clear then you can clear the cart, but if it fails then keep the cart data so to allow the user to redo the transaction again later.